# MonthName(month(now) + x) ..... error on 13; easy fix?

Tags: vba, excel

Once `month(now) + x => 13` I get an error using `MonthName` in VBA.

Without building out too much more code is there an easy workaround I'm missing?  Only thing I can think of is to set some conditionals inside the loop to adjust it so the `month(now) + x` reverts back to 1 once it hits 13.

Also looks like I'll have a problem with `Year(Now)` too once it gets past 13 but one thing at a time.

Code:

```
Sub Do_Stuff_Button()

expand = 2

MsgBox Day(Now)

ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 6) = "'" & MonthName(Month(Now), False)
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 6) = "'" & Year(Now)

Do While expand > 0
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, (6 - expand)) = "'" & Year(Now)
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, (6 + expand)) = "'" & Year(Now)
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, (6 - expand)) = "'" & MonthName((Month(Now) - expand), False)
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, (6 + expand)) = "'" & MonthName((Month(Now) + expand), False)
expand = expand - 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: didnt understand 100%, but why not make it `(month(now) + x) % 13`?

Comment: What do you want it to be, when it's month 13, 14, etc? The reason you're getting the issue is because there technically is no month 13...You could throw an If statement in there saying like (obviously psuedocode) `If month(now) + x >= 13, x = 12, month(now)+x)`?

Comment: Yeah once it hits 13 i want it to go to January.  Going to have a list selection with the dates to start on then want 4 months back and forth populated.  @pvinis mod 13?

Comment: @Ross, ok now i got it. month gives [1-12] and you need 13 to become 1 basically. the `mod` way is this then. `(((month(now) + x)-1) % 12) + 1`. so you get the number of the month with the x, and then move it to [0-11], then mod it with 12, then get it up to [1-12] again. at that point, its just annoying, so an if is probably better for reading and understanding.

Comment: Yeah using the mod works, but have been switching to `DateAdd` now as it gets rid of errors I make and also counts leap years etc.  Thanks for all the help(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DateAdd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262710(v=vs.60).aspx).

`Debug.Print MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", 1, Date)))`

If you were to pass a number into the function, which is greater than the number of remaining months in the current year, then it will calculate the month continuing into the following year.

**Example**

`Debug.Print MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", 5, Date)))`

The above will return `March`.

Comment: Seems `DateAdd` works better than using mod, gets rid of manual error by me during coding.  Selected as the new best answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the Mod operator to check if there is any value remaining and then pass that as the month value

```
Dim monthVal As Integer

If (Month(Now) + x) Mod 12 > 0 Then
    monthVal = (Month(Now) + x) Mod 12
Else
    monthVal = Month(Now) + x
End If

MonthName (monthVal)
```

Comment: Yeah thanks I'll work something in it like this.  I always forget about mod / %.  Probably cause I don't fully understand them yet :)

Comment: @Ross  don't forget to mark it as answered if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Format for MonthName:

```
Debug.Print Format(Now(), "mmmm yyyy")
Debug.Print Format(DateAdd("m", 1, Now()), "mmmm yyyy")
```

Deals with year rollover as well as month roll over